# Iterate Data Returned from Web Service in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've written a PowerShell script to call a Web Service using the new PS 2.0 commands. I would like to know how to iterate the `$events` result.  The code works in returning data, I'm just not sure what the result data type is or how to iterate thru it.

Here's the code:

```
#connect to web service
$ap = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://cantreallygiveyouthis/api/services/data?wsdl

#specify event params
$params = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3ices_AlarmPointWebService_wsdl.EventSearchParameters
$params.datasource  =  "runtime"
$params.startDate  =  "01/09/2011 3:00:00 PM"
$params.endDate  =  "01/09/2011 3:15:00 PM"

#call web service
$events = $ap.FindEvents("username", "pass", "", "", "", ":)", $params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious choice would be `$events | Get-Member` or `$events[0] | Get-Member` to find out what's available to you. `$events[0].Gettype()` can be useful as well.

Comment: I tried `$events | Get-Memeber` before but not $events[0].  Silly me.  Hey, obvious to some :)  Thx for your help!